# Async gives syntax error in a method(function)

Tags: javascript, node.js

Environment: **Node.js v7.2.0**

I am trying to use `async` keyword to create method that returns a promise.

I get the following error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token function

```
this.getFrame = async function(data) {
                      ^^^^^^^^
```

Here is the example:

```js
function Parser() {
  this.receiveBuffer = Buffer.alloc(0);
  this.frameBuff = Buffer.alloc(0);

  /* GET FRAME ******************************** */
  this.getFrame = async function(data) { //The ERROR appears here!!!
    for (let byte of data) {
      if (byte !== 0x0d && byte !== 0x0a) {
        // console.log()
        this.receiveBuffer = Buffer.concat([
          this.receiveBuffer,
          Buffer.from([byte])
        ]);
        // console.log("Buffer is long: " + this.receiveBuffer.length);
      } else {
        this.frameBuff = this.receiveBuffer;
        this.receiveBuffer = Buffer.alloc(0);
        // console.log(this.frameBuff);
        return this.frameBuff;
      }
    }
  };
  /* ******************************** */

  this.parse = function(frame) {
    console.log(frame);
  };
}
```

Comment: browser IE11 by any chance?

Comment: Where are you trying to run this code? Looks like your environment doesn't support async/await syntax.

Comment: Node.js version 7.2.0

Comment: Btw, nothing that you do inside this function appears to be asynchronous, so why are you trying to use a promise at all?

Comment: ahhh, yeah, you need later node

Comment: Please always start your quest by googling the error message - Even for X/Y problems ;)

Comment: @Bergi
It returns only when valid frame is received, hence after undefined time

Comment: that's not what async/await is for ... oh and `It returns only when valid frame is received` no, it doesn't

Comment: Why not.......?

Comment: Yes the Node is too old.

Comment: because there's nothing asynchronous at all in that function - that's why not

Comment: How do you define asynchronous?

Comment: @Hairi The function returns as soon as the loop is finished. It doesn't wait for any outside event.

Comment: think setTimeout

Comment: If you can do `let parsedData = Parser.getFrame(someData); console.log(parsedData)` and not see undefined, then it is not async

Comment: Ok all, I installed Node.js  `v10.11.0` and it works now. The SO question marked as a duplicate is correct. Thank you all.